# How to write data in excel drop down list in java?

Tags: python, java, excel, apache-poi

There is City drop down on cell A1 and I want to select the New York value that is in the list.

When I try to write the New York value in the cell A1, cell is getting changed to normal cell that is causing issue when I have to process for another operation. I want it to be dropdown list type cell even after writing. How can I do it?

Comment: Please provide the code what you have tried.

Comment: There are examples on the web - eg https://www.roseindia.net/tutorials/poi/XLCellDropDown.shtml - the feature is called Data Validation

Comment: Please show the code of what you are doing. Data validation settings are on sheet level. So even if I create the row and the cell new, the data validation settings remain. One would must recreating the whole sheet to loose the data validation settings.